# How can I get all class properties, even if optional with typescript?

Tags: typescript

When I try to get property names from a class, `getOwnPropertyNames` returns only properties with values.

Is there a way to get ALL properties, and not just the ones with values?

```js
class Klass {
    firstValue: string;
    secondValue!: string;

    constructor() {
        this.firstValue = 'withValue';
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
    }
}

new Klass();
```

Result:

```js
[ 'firstValue' ]
```

Comment: A property with no value is a property that doesn't exist. I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: That is not compiling JavaScript.

Comment: Actually I’m using Typescript.. When trying vanilla js works as intended..

Comment: Then replace the javascript tag with typescript and fix the title

Comment: @Samathingamajig done.. sorry for that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, a prop without any value won't be visible by [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).

Setting the prop to, for example, `false` or `undefined`, will show it;

```js
this.test_1;
this.test_2 = false;
this.test_3 = undefined;

const allPropertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
console.log(allPropertyNames.includes('test_1'));   // FALSE
console.log(allPropertyNames.includes('test_2'));   // TRUE
console.log(allPropertyNames.includes('test_3'));   // TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting default values to properties will allow you to get all property names in that object as all no value properties are `undefined` so it is not exist in object when you print it.

But why do you need such information? in the question code sample you already know all names that you need or will use.

Answer (score 0):

You should set all possible properties upfront in the constructor. The *optional* ones should be set to null.

```js
constructor() {
  this.firstValue = 'first';
  this.secondValue = null;
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this));
}
```